# ECS - Components inside components?

Tags: javascript, entity-system, component-based, entity-component

Reading up on ECS, I've tried to implement a simple 'game', if you can call it that.
Basic concepts :

You have planets(entity), they produce gold. (**gold** is a component inside planet)
Planets can build buildings on themselves(**Buildings** component)
A building(entity) has associated gold costs(**Costs** component)

But costs component has **Gold** in it(or it needs to anyway)

As to my question :
Am I close with my interpretation of ECS(Should components be inside other components?)
Are resources a valid Component? if not, where would it make sense to place them?

Edit for clarity :

ECS - Entity-Component-System.
My entities are empty hash tables of components.
My components are used inside systems for game logic, the Treasury entity has a Gold component and the IncomeSystem updates that component.

Other components (Buildable, Population, Moveable)

Comment: When dealing with ECS, it's better to describe what E, C and S mean to you and your implementation, since there is no standard in what an ECS is.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt - Edited for clarity, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no "right" or "wrong" way to structure a game's software architecture. Just ways which work or don't work for you.

*Usually* you wouldn't nest components. What you would do instead is nest entities by making them parents and children of each other.

- The `Universe` entity has many `Planet` child-entities
- A `Planet` entity has many `Building` child-entities

I am not sure if it makes sense to make `Gold` a full-fledged component. Is it really more than just a number? Does "gold" have any behavior or interaction with components of other entities? If not I would rather expect it to be a simple variable in the `BuildCost`-component, the `ResourceProducer`-component and the `Treasury` - component.

The only situation where you might have components with components is if you have some game feature which is so complex that you would implement it with a completely independent EC-System inside the component which hosts it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been debating with myself whether or not Gold should be a Component, I think the reality is it shouldn't.